# WPML changes WordPress language to default when redirecting from login page

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I am building a bilingual website using WordPress and WPML(the translation plugin [WPML](https://wpml.org/)), also to handle login and registration I used [Theme my login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/), however since it's not compatible with WPML, I had to find an alternative (tried clean-login ) but still no luck.

The problem I faced with theme my login; it's not supporting templates for both languages only the English part (the other language is Arabic), while using clean-login you can't modify it's templates (while I needed to add some fields to user registration).

Finally I followed the tutorial in this [link](https://github.com/tutsplus/personalize-login-tutorial-part-3/tree/master/personalize-login) to build my own login and registration plugin, the problem I'm facing now is that each time a login is made, I'm being redirected to the user profile (which is the correct behavior) but instead of keeping the same language from the login page, it redirects to the user profile with the default language although I was trying to login from the Arabic login page.

I tried several fixes for the language redirection problem; like trying to modify the locale using wp locale filter through a [custom function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49451/change-locale-at-runtime), or by using a conditional on the $_GET['lang'], unfortunately nothing worked.

An example for the various solutions I tried using the $_GET['lang'] parameter; 
setting a public variable ($site_lang) in the custom plugin class:

```
public $site_lang;
public function __construct() {

    global $sitepress;
    $current_lang = $sitepress->get_current_language();

    if ( isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'ar'){
        $this->site_lang = 'ar';
    }else{
        $this->site_lang = 'en_US';
    }
}
```

Another variation using session through the plugin WP_SESSION

```
global $sitepress;
$current_lang = $sitepress->get_current_language();
$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance(); 
$wp_session['act_lang'] = 'ar';
if (!isset($_GET['lang'])){
    $wp_session['act_lang'] = 'en';
}else{
    $wp_session['act_lang'] = 'ar';
}
$this->site_lang = $wp_session['act_lang'];
```

and the redirect on registration error function, which is one of many functions that deals with redirect, I'm putting it here as an example on how I'm using the public variable for redirection

```
public function maybe_redirect_at_authenticate( $user, $username, $password ) {

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) {

      $login_url = ($this->site_lang == 'ar') ? site_url( 'تسجيل-الدخول/?lang=ar' ) 
      : home_url( 'member-login' );
      $login_url = add_query_arg( array('login' => $error_codes), $login_url );
      wp_redirect( $login_url );

    }
}
```

If anyone has a solution on how to keep the language the same after redirection, I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: did you find any solution?the question is for 2 years ago but i faced the same problem,when redirection between pages the language change to default one!